# Variables as a full query shows a "unclosed parenthesis in media query expression" error

Tags: css, ionic-framework, sass, ionic2

I'm using Sass with Ionic 2, and I created the following variables to apply my media queries,

```
$small:   568px;
$screen:        "only screen" !default;
$small-max :   "#{$screen} and (max-width: #{$small})";
```

And use it on my scss files like this:

```
@media #{$small-max} {
 // My styles
}
```

But I'm getting the following error,

> Error: unclosed parenthesis in media query expression

I can't see what I'm doing wrong here. Am I missing something?

Comment: The provided code does not produce any errors: http://www.sassmeister.com/gist/e3b539a3b6d353f174d51a352c9083cf

Comment: Code is working fine

Comment: Is this related: https://github.com/sass/libsass/issues/1794?

Comment: I got a very exact same issue. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

sass-loader version is low.
Try to upgrade the version. This problem does not occur with the upgraded version

Try this combination:

```
"sass": "^1.32.4"
"sass-loader": "^12.6.0"
```